# SQL Server 2008 Express connection string raises instance failure exception

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, connection-string

I'm using the following code to open a DB connection to an SQL Server 2008 Express instance and run queries from a DB script

```
private void ExecuteSql(String serverName, String sql)
{
    String connectionString = String.Format("Server={0};Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;User Instance=False;Context Connection=False;Connect Timeout=300;", serverName.Trim());
    MessageBox.Show(connectionString);

    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.Connection = sqlConnection;
    sqlConnection.Open();

    try
    {
        var scripts = Regex.Split(sql, @"^\s*GO\s* ($ | \-\- .*$)", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        foreach (var splitScript in scripts.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).Select(x => x.Trim(' ', '\r', '\n')))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(splitScript);
            command.CommandText = splitScript;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

When I run the code I always get an exception message "Instance failure"

If I replace the line

```
String connectionString = String.Format("Server={0};Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;User Instance=False;Context Connection=False;Connect Timeout=300;", serverName.Trim());
```

by the same line but hard-coding the server name parameter

```
String connectionString = "Server=MACHINE-NAME\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;User Instance=False;Context Connection=False;Connect Timeout=300;";
```

everything works fine.

I've tried many different ways to create the connection string (`String.format`, `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`, string concatenation... ) but so far all of them raise the same problem when using the `serverName` parameter instead of hard-coding it

Comment: Check serverName content (specially for "\\").

Comment: Instead of using `String.Format` use [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx). Then you can do `var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(/* Your old string without the Server= */);` then just `builder.DataSource = serverName.Trim()` to set the server.

Comment: I've already tried with SqlConnectionStringBuilder and it did not work. I've also used "Data Source" instead of "Server" with no luck. I've added the MessageBox to clearly show the string content and neither with one slash nor with two slashes have worked. I've tried several combinations and all of them raise the "Instance Failure" exception

Comment: Apparently, in the architecture I'm working on, you cannot let the user decide the host name but only the server name. Therefore I changed the connection string to include **./** as host name and everything works fine now